# Broadcast received video signal via red5

Tags: red5, jwplayer

What needs to be done: Broadcast a live event to a webpage. Each webpage visitor sees JW (or similar) player.

How I understand the logic:

1. TV bus at the event translates video signal to Red5 via internet.
2. Red5 broadcasts received signal and offers it to JW players at rtmp://myserver.com/oflaDemo.
3. JW player does the job and displays stream to visitors.

How do I manage received signal with Red5?

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat accurate, although i'd recommend you to use a CDN for it, and just have jwplayer fetch a live stream from the cdn.